# Writing large matrix into a file in octave because it does not fit in memory

Tags: octave

I am currently writing an Octave program to find similarities in a body of text.

I have a 20,000 x 50 matrix and I need to find the cosine similarity which will be a 20,000 x 20,000 matrix.

I am using octave, but it gives me a memory heap error. In order to fix this, I thought of writing the data into a file.

Will someone suggest an idea to process a matrix that is too large to fit into memory at once?

```
for i=1:length(X)-1  
  x=i  
  for a=0:(i-1)  
    dlmwrite('test',0.00000,",",(x-1),a);  
  end  
  for j=i+1:length(X)  
    s = abs(dot(X(i,:),X(j,:))/norm(X(i,:))*norm(X(j,:)));  
    dlmwrite('test',s,",",(i-1),(j-1));  
  end  
end
```

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: when the arrays are to big, you can save them in a redis instance with go-redis: https://github.com/markuman/go-redis#gnu-octave-and-matlab-special But you still needs enough memory for redis to hold such big data.